# Subtotal not showing up in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a heavily modified instance of Magento 1.9 and it does not show Subtotal in the Checkout.

I have found out that in file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php`
method `renderTotals()` always returns empty string, while it should return html. For comparison, in clear installation of Magento 1.9 it does return html strings.

How to find out the cause of this? 
Is something broken? Is there a setting in the admin section that disables this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found how to make

```
<?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
```

work, but instead this is my solution which works really good.
I have just replaced renderTotals() call with this code:

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $total) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $total->getTitle(); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="a-right">
            $<?php echo $total->getValue(); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
```